# Recursively get every nth element from array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, recursion

I have an array of colors that I need to recursively get every nth element to generate a legend. The colors array might look something like this:

```
[
'red',
'dark_red',
'dark_dark_red',
'green',
'dark_green',
'dark_dark_green',
'blue',
'dark_blue',
'dark_dark_blue'
]
```

I have a variable amount of legend items that I want to generate colors for. I want to be able to generate the colors based off of the index when looping through the legend items in a pattern like so:

```
1 - green
2 - blue
3 - dark_red
4 - dark_green
5 - dark_blue
6 - etc...
```

How might I go about this? I tried using modulus and a double-loop statement but was not able to generate the colors properly.

Comment: Is the index starts with 0 - red?

Comment: If the list length is variable and `n` can be arbitrarily chosen, you can get repeating loops, like if you choose every 3rd element from your 9-item list, you'll just get the 'dark_dark_x' colors. What behavior would you want in that situation?

Comment: I don't see how recursion would play into this. I also don't see why a double-loop would play into it either. *Modulus* would seem the way to go, as in `i % amount of colors`.

Comment: Indeed: why do you **need** to use recursion?

Comment: Are you basically trying to alternate colors, with a different shade of each base color each time? If so, I think there's an easier way.

Comment: If this is cyclic, from `green` to `blue` involves three steps, from `blue` to `dark_red` involves four steps, then each of the others involves three steps.  So what should we make of your "etc"?  What would be next?  Unless your step is [coprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers) with the list length, you will cycle through a subset of the elements.  Is this what you want?

Comment: @ssilas777 Yes, sorry.

@Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I don't **need** recursion, I'm afraid I misused that term here in my tiredness. What I need is to get the first set of every 3 colors, then to get the _next_ set of every three colors (starting from index 1: dark_red) and so on.

@slappy I'm open to other ways, if you have a suggestion.

@ScottSauyet the next in the succession would be `dark_dark_red`, then `dark_dark_green`, then `dark_dark_blue`. Yes, that is what I want.

Answer (score 2):

To get the `nthItems`:

```js
function nthItems(array, n){
  const r = [];
  for(let i=n-1,l=array.length; i<l; i+=n){
    r.push(array[i]);
  }
  return r;
}
const a = [
  'red',
  'dark_red',
  'dark_dark_red',
  'green',
  'dark_green',
  'dark_dark_green',
  'blue',
  'dark_blue',
  'dark_dark_blue'
];
console.log(nthItems(a, 2));
console.log(nthItems(a, 3));
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm afraid I was unclear in my initial question. I know how to get every nth element, but I need to be able to get every nth element, then move onto the next "subsection" of the data, which is every nth item starting from index 1. Then after that, every nth item starting from index 2.

Comment: The first index is really `0` in an Array. *"subsection"*? What do you mean by that?

Answer (score 0):

StackSlave's answer is the most efficient way but if you want a recursive way you could do

```js
const a = [
  'red',
  'dark_red',
  'dark_dark_red',
  'green',
  'dark_green',
  'dark_dark_green',
  'blue',
  'dark_blue',
  'dark_dark_blue'
];

const nthItems = (array, n) => {
  const results = [];
  const addItem = index => {
    if (index < array.length) {
      results.push(array[index]);
      addItem(index + n);
    }
  };
  addItem(0);
  return results;
};

console.log(nthItems(a, 2));
console.log(nthItems(a, 3));
```

But this is recursive purely for the sake of recursion, it adds values to the stack unnecessarily when a for loop will do.